# Google Analytics - Separate Views For Subdomains Aren't Returning Data

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I've setup new views in Google Analytics last week, but I'm not getting any data from them at all.

We have our main site: `http:// www.example.com` which is using the old version of GA:
`var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X'],
    ['_setDomainName', 'www.example.com'],
    ['_trackPageview'],
    ['hq._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X'],
    ['hq._setDomainName', 'www.example.com'],
    ['hq._trackPageview']
);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();`

We have a subdomain at `https://store.example.com` and the platform we're using (Virto) considers `https://store.example.com/en-us/blue-widgets`  and `https://store.example.com/en-us/red-widgets` as two separate websites.  It lets us pick which one of those directories is default, so when you enter `https://store.example.com` into your address bar, you're redirected to `https://store.example.com/en-us/blue-widgets`. The store subdomain has the new version of GA:

`(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');`

```

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto', { 'allowLinker': true });
// Load the plugin.
ga('require', 'linker');
// Define which domains to autoLink.
ga('linker:autoLink', ['store.example.com']);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

```

So here is what I did for a new view just for the BLUE WIDGET Site Data: 
Under New VIEW, Website's URL: I picked "`HTTPS://`" and then entered "store.example.com/en-us/blue-widgets".

And then I created a Filter on this view for traffic through BLUE WIDGETS only:
"INCLUDE ONLY", "TRAFFIC TO THE HOSTNAME", "THAT CONTAIN", HOSTNAME: `https://store.example.com/en-us/blue-widgets`

I did that for both Blue and Red Widget sites, but I'm not getting data back on either view. I'm obviously doing something wrong. I hope all that makes sense and someone can see where the problem is. Please let me know if there's more info I can provide.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really confused.

Comment: Haha, yeah I was afraid of that! Where are you getting lost at? Hopefully I can explain it better.